# Poco::StreamSocket: detect sending fail

Tags: c++, sockets, poco-libraries

Lets say I have a message queue, e.g. `std::deque<std::vector<uint8_t>>()`
I made a `poll()` (or select), and know that socket is ready for writing.

I do:

```
const auto& message = _messageQueue.front();
_socket.sendBytes(message.data(), message.size());
_messageQueue.pop_front();
```

For example, I can do an assertion that bytes sent is the same as message size, but Poco documentations says that StreamSocket::sendBytes()

```
Returns the number of bytes sent, which may be less than the number of bytes specified.
```

Poco documentation also does not say anything what actually `setBlocking()` method does. Does it blocks until ACK packet received, and throws on socket error?

Comment: Read here: [Blocking vs. non-blocking sockets](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html).

Answer (score 0):

> example, I can do an assertion that bytes sent is the same as message size, but Poco documentations says that `StreamSocket::sendBytes()`
>
> > Returns the number of bytes sent, which may be less than the number of bytes specified.

This is only correct in non-blocking mode. In blocking mode, I t will transfer all the bytes before it returns, unless there is an error. This is defined by Posix, not by Poco. If there is an actual question here, I can't see it.

> Poco documentation also does not say anything what actually `setBlocking()` method does. Does it blocks until ACK packet received?

No. It *causes* future reads to block until there is data or EOS or an error, and writes to blockuntil the data hasbeen copied into the socket send buffer.